# Is it possible to see the comments of a deleted answer?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-questions

Some days ago, I received a new answer to [one of my questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/89434/is-it-true-that-ethanol-can-have-some-positive-effects/100813). I found this answer interesting and I wanted to check the comments associated to it if any. Unfortunately, this answer has been deleted.

I would like to know why and I suppose this answer received bad comments and downvotes. If it is the case, I'm really curious about these comments. I'm sure they could help me to understand the topic better.

Is there a way to retrieve the comments associated to a deleted question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, the deleted answer is below, and [this is the Guardian link](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2019/may/06/heres-why-moderate-drinking-is-probably-not-good-for-you). The answer was posted by a user who is no longer registered, either of their own choice, or because of bad behavior (spam) elsewhere.

[image]

Please note that the Guardian is not a scientific publication by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Thanks. I agree about the scientific credibility of The Guardian but there are links to scientific publications in it.

Comment: “ Please note that the Guardian is not a scientific publication by any stretch of the imagination” made my evening.

Answer (score 1):

The answer didn't receive any upvotes, no downvotes and there were no comments placed.

Deleted answers, their comment history and the number of votes on them are, afaik, only visible to the mod team.

[Here is the link](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/100813/9943) I have from the deleted answer; I wonder if anyone can view it, barred the mods and possibly the answerer.

Comment: No, I can't see it.

Comment: 10k+ users can see the deleted answer and any comments associated with it at the time it was deleted, but we can't see the comment *history* on any question or answer - only mods can see that.